# Macro for determining which geographical area a given geographical coordinate is located at

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have geographically different areas whose boundaries are given by sets of geographical coordinates in CSV files (area1.csv, area2.csv, area3.csv, .....). The geographical coordinates in the CSV files are comma-separated latitude/longitude pairs. In an excel sheet, I have other sets of latitude/longitude coordinates in columns A and B of 'Sheet 1'. Now, I want a macro which determines the location of each latitude/longitude pair and writes the result to another sheet in excel, say 'Sheet 2', with the area of each entry in the third column or writes the result to a CSV file.

For example, suppose we have the following rectangular areas defined as follows:

Area1.csv:
latitude,longitude
0,0
2,0
0,2
2,2
0,0

Area2.csv:
latitude,longitude
2,0
4,0
4,2
2,2
2,0

Area3.csv:
latitude,longitude
0,2
2,2
2,4
0,4
0,2

Area4.csv:
latitude,longitude
2,2
4,2
4,4
2,4
2,2

Let's say we want to locate the following pairs of coordinates that we have in excel 'sheet 1' in columns 'A' and 'B':
latitude    longitude
1   1
3   1
1   3
3   3

Well, it is true that the first point or coordinate (1,1) is in Area1, the second (3,1) is in Area2, the third (1,3) is in Area3 and the fourth is in Area4. So, the macro should copy the coordinate pairs in 'Sheet 1' to 'Sheet 2' by appending the corresponding area in the third column i.e. 'C'. In this case, 'Sheet 2' should look like the following:

latitude    longitude   Area
1   1   Area1
3   1   Area2
1   3   Area3
3   3   Area4

I have never programmed in VBA before. I really do not have any idea how to do it. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First add this macro to your excel document as a new module.  Press ALT-F11 to open the VB editor. Press ALT-I-M to insert a new module.

Copy the code below into the module.

```
Sub getarea()
Dim coordx, coordy, coords, area_location As String

For record_ROW = 2 To 5 '<======== set sheet row limits here
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    'read value to be matched
    coordx = Trim(Range("A" & record_ROW))
    coordy = Trim(Range("B" & record_ROW))
    coords = coordx & "," & coordy
    area_location = "undetermined"

    'search for answer in Sheet2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    For source_ROW = 2 To 6 '<======== set sheet row limits here
        source_coords = Trim(Range("A" & source_ROW))
        If coords = source_coords Then area_location = "Area1"
    Next source_ROW

    'search for answer in Sheet3
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    For source_ROW = 2 To 6 '<======== set sheet row limits here
        source_coords = Trim(Range("A" & source_ROW))
        If coords = source_coords Then area_location = "Area2"
    Next source_ROW

    'search for answer in Sheet4
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    For source_ROW = 2 To 6 '<======== set sheet row limits here
        source_coords = Trim(Range("A" & source_ROW))
        If coords = source_coords Then area_location = "Area3"
    Next source_ROW

    'search for answer in Sheet5
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    For source_ROW = 2 To 6 '<======== set sheet row limits here
        source_coords = Trim(Range("A" & source_ROW))
        If coords = source_coords Then area_location = "Area4"
    Next source_ROW

    'write the answer
    Range("'Sheet1'!C" & record_ROW) = area_location
Next record_ROW

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

When you are ready to start, press F8 to step through the macro one step at a time.  When you are ready to let it rip, press ALT-F4 to close the editor.  Press ALT-F8 and choose "getarea" to run the macro.

This macro will run comparatively slow because of all the screen updating.  You can disable screen updates by adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` just be sure to re-enable it later with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.  There are other ways out there to speed up processing time, to provide progress indicators, and other bells and whistles.  But there is no harm if you run it as is.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I understood it correctly, the code assumes the definition of the areas (boundaries) are saved in 'Shee2','Sheet3','Sheet4' and 'Sheet5'. With this, I run it with the example I provided in the first post. Unfortunately, it could not return the areas associated to each pair of points correctly. It does run but does not output the areas. All it display is 'undetermined'. Also, I am planning to use this program with approximately 2000 areas. This would mean that I have to have 2001 sheets in the same excel file. It seems it is not going to help this way. Any other way?

Comment: My intuition tells me that the algorithm should look like the following: LOOP1 POINTS [ START WITH Point1; LOOP2 CSVFiles [ START Area1.csv;] IF (Point1 is in Area1, GOTO LOOP1); ElSE (GOTO LOOP2); All POINTS? IF(YES), EXIT and RETURN AREAS; ELSE GOTO LOOP1;]

Comment: In order to write the code, I created a working excel file.  I think you will find it much easier to follow a working copy.  Do you have a dropbox account or some other way to receive an uploaded sample file?  Unfortunately, this forum does not provide attachments.

Comment: I do not have dropbox account but I have a gmail account: zafidess@gmail.com Thanks a lot.